# I am unable to fetch partial data from related table in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

One order have many order items and if i exclude one of its order items, then it will exclude all other order items of that order id. Can somebody please tell me why?

Here is order-id = 8056313100 and two order-items that have ids = 8056313101, 8056313102.

Here is **View.py**

```
order = Order.objects.distinct().filter(orderitem__status=request.data['status']).exclude(orderitem__order_item_id=8056313102)
serializer = ListOrderSerializer(order, many=True)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

**Serializer.py**

```
class ListOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
order_items = ListOrderItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

class Meta:
  model = Order
  exclude = ('id',)
```

Order-item-id = 8056313101 will also exclude. Please help me.

Comment: Is your endpoint supposed to return order items or orders?

Comment: Orders that contains order-items inside.

Comment: Please reply something.